# Why are extra records appearing in file?

Tags: javascript, php

This code should write one more file record than the number of times the button is clicked (because it writes one on entry). But if I click ten times I get at least 12 records. The extra records appear up to 60 seconds late. For a while I thought it must be a bounce problem but that is a very long bounce! Any idea why this is happening? I've tried it on multiple browsers and OSs and the only place it doesn't happen is on my Easyphp server.

timerecordshort.php

```
<?php
$utime=substr(microtime(),11,10).substr(microtime(),2,6);
$fp=fopen('testfile.txt','ab');
fwrite($fp, $utime."*");
if (false === $fp) die("bad write");
fclose($fp);
if (false === $fp) die("bad close");
?>
<button onclick="endFunction()">record short time</button>
<script>
function endFunction() 
{
    var myWindow = window.open("timerecordshort.php", "_self");
}
</script>
</body>
</h
```

Comment: Works fine here using Windows 7, Apache 2.4.18 and PHP7.0.4 and PHP5.6.15 and PHP5.5.30. And I get no late arrivals, even with the off `</h` tag

Comment: @Riggs, sorry about the </h. Thanks for trying, I gives me some more theories to work on.